# Is there a way where i can pass the value to a webpage using VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am using SAP Bex where after login, i need to fill in the text boxes to get the data. How can i parse the data to web using Excel VBA?

I was able to achieve the same to parse ID and Password. But didn't work for the other boxes on the next page

```
    Sub test()

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    my_url = "https://jwpwas.maxtree.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/pcd!3aportal_content!2fcom.sap.pct!2fplatform_add_ons!2fcom.sap.ip.bi!2fiViews!2fcom.sap.ip.bi.bex?QUERY=YZCSMSOSU1_Q0002_MTD_ENA_BC_P&VARIABLE_SCREEN=X&DUMMY=1"

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate my_url

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    End With

' Input the userid and password
    ie.document.getElementById("j_username").Value = "myID"
    ie.document.getElementById("j_password").Value = "myPassword"
    ie.document.getElementById("uidPasswordLogon").click

   ie.document.getElementById("DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_cvl_VAR_2_INPUT_inp").value = "11"

**---- Below is the html source -----**

    <INPUT onchange="sapUrMapi_InputField_change('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_cvl_VAR_1_INPUT_inp',event);" tabIndex=0 onkeyup="sapUrMapi_InputField_KeyUp('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_cvl_VAR_1_INPUT_inp',event);" onfocus="sapUrMapi_InputField_focus('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_cvl_VAR_1_INPUT_inp',event);" onblur="sapUrMapi_InputField_Blur('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_cvl_VAR_1_INPUT_inp',event);" id=DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_cvl_VAR_1_INPUT_inp class="urEdf2TxtEnbl urEdf2TxtHlp" onselectstart="sapUrMapi_InputField_onselectstart('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_cvl_VAR_1_INPUT_inp',event);" onkeydown="sapUrMapi_InputField_keydown('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_cvl_VAR_1_INPUT_inp',event);" name=DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_cvl_VAR_1_INPUT_inp ct="I" f4always="false" ti="0" tp="STRING" st="" autocomplete="off" oldvalue>

Input name is "DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_cvl_VAR_1_INPUT_inp"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zqob.jpg)

Comment: Does it show any error ? I think after clicking you need to add the `ReadyState` code so that page can load, and fill your values after it has been loaded fully.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work?  Your code identifies 4 elements but only tries to interact with the first 3.  There is no attempt to interact with the fourth element, which by the way, doesn't exist in the html source you provided.  Seems like your code works just fine and you need to reevaluate your expectations or identify the problem and update your question.

Comment: https://ibb.co/LCdt6wh - Link to the html elements screenshot

Comment: 1) Is the id constant across login attempts? 2) Is it within a parent frame or iframe?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. `ie.document.getElementById("DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_cvl_VAR_2_INPUT_inp")` does not actually do anything. No method is invoked.  What can you possibly expect other than for it not to work? I can write `Sheet2.Range("A1")` and complain that it doesn't work until I am blue in the face but, it will never work because it does not do anything.  It just sits there and creates an error.  On top of that, `DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_cvl_VAR_2_INPUT_inp` is not anywhere in the HTML source you listed in your answer, in short, you're doing nothing and you're doing it with the wrong element.

Comment: I have added the value to the element id and screenshot for your reference. I was not able to copy paste the entire html code,